Error estimation in weighted cubic fitting
Given the dataset $(t_i, y_i)$ with absolute errors $\varepsilon_{y_i}$, I want to fit a weighted cubic function and get the errors on interpolated values $\hat{y}(t)$:
$$
\hat{y}(t) = \sum^{3}_{j=0}c_jt^j
$$
where $c_j$ are the coefficients determined by the weighted fitting process.
Calculating the residuals and chi squared is straightforward:
$$
r_i = y_i - \hat{y}(t_i)
$$
$$
\chi^2 = \sum^n_{i=1}\left( \frac{r_i}{\varepsilon_{y_i}}\right)^2
$$
...but it's unclear to me where to go from here to get errors on $\hat{y}$ values. How do I estimate the error on the interpolation $\hat{y}(t)$?

What is $\varepsilon$ here?

$\varepsilon$ is absolute error

That helps a bit. Do you give an explicit definition of it in terms of the variables here?

Both $y_i$ and $\varepsilon_{y_i}$ are empirical. Specifically, $\varepsilon_{y_i}$ is based on the quality of fit of raw data to a user-selected model plus an extrapolation.

From the description you want to fit the data but not to interpolate them. Interpolation is about finding a model function that passes over all data points. On the other hand,  fitting approximates some function to data.
To problem is a weighted least squares. You need to calculate first the estimators and covariance matrix $ V_c$ of the parameters $c_j$. This can be done in Python with WLS in statsmodels. The error in the fitted model is calculated by propagating the errors of the estimators,
$$
Var(\hat{y}) = \left( \nabla \hat{y} \right)^T \; V_c \; \nabla \hat{y}
$$
With $\nabla \hat{y} $ the gradient wrt the $ c_j $'s. The error you are after is the square root of this variance. This as a function of the independent variable t also gives de error band $$\hat{y} \pm \sigma (\hat{y}) $$.
